# TryParseExact does not convert a string with timezone

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, timezone-offset, tryparse

I have a string "2023-04-13T07:03:20-03:00", and I want to convert to `DateTime` with a specific **format "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss"**, so i'm using the `TryParseExact` method, but I just receive `false` as return.

This is the code I'm working on. When the variable comes without timezone, the conversion happens normally, however with the timezone no format works.

In the documentation I didn't find anything that says that this way I'm doing it is wrong.

I also tried setting the datestyle to `AssumeUniversal`, it didn't work.

If anyone can give me some clarification I would appreciate it.

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Globalization;
                    
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var formats = new[]{
            "o",
                        "s",
                        "t", "T",
                        "M/yy",
                        "dd-MM-yy",
        "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss",};
        
        foreach(var format in formats)
        {
            DateTime dat1;
            DateTime dat2;
            Console.WriteLine(format);
            Console.WriteLine("");
            Console.WriteLine(DateTime.TryParseExact("2023-04-13T07:03:20-03:00", formats, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out dat1) ? dat1.ToString(format) : "false");
            Console.WriteLine(DateTime.TryParseExact("2023-04-13T07:03:20", formats, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out dat2) ? dat2.ToString(format) : "false");
            Console.WriteLine("");
            Console.WriteLine("--------------------");
        }
    }
}
```

The result:

o

false
2023-04-13T07:03:20.0000000

---

s

false
2023-04-13T07:03:20

---

t

false
7:03 AM

---

T

false
7:03:20 AM

---

M/yy

false
4/23

---

dd-MM-yy

false
13-04-23

---

yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss

false
2023-04-13T07:03:20

---

Comment: None of your formats allow for a UTC offset (which isn't the same as a time zone, btw). Why would you expect yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss to match 2023-04-13T07:03:20-03:00? The latter isn't an example of the former format... I suggest you specify a format which *does* include the UTC offset, probably in the form "zzz" at the end. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings#zzzSpecifier

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should include the timezone offset in the format. You can do it using "K".

```cs
var formats = new[] { "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssK" };
```

Comment: i read in documentation "The format of the string representation must match a specified format exactly.", I thought "Z" was the correct letter, i was wrong. thanks thanks thankssss

Answer (score 0):

The format "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss" that you are using to parse the date and time string "2023-04-13T07:03:20-03:00" is correct. However, the issue you are facing is related to the timezone information in the input string.

The timezone information "-03:00" is not recognized by the TryParseExact method, which expects a timezone offset in the format "+/-HH:mm". To fix this, you can modify the input string to replace the colon ":" with an empty string before attempting to parse it.

Here's an updated version of your code that should work:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Globalization;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var formats = new[]{
            "o",
            "s",
            "t", "T",
            "M/yy",
            "dd-MM-yy",
            "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss",
        };

        var input = "2023-04-13T07:03:20-03:00".Replace(":", "");
        
        foreach(var format in formats)
        {
            DateTime dat1;
            Console.WriteLine(format);
            Console.WriteLine("");
            Console.WriteLine(DateTime.TryParseExact(input, format, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out dat1) ? dat1.ToString(format) : "false");
            Console.WriteLine("");
            Console.WriteLine("--------------------");
        }
    }
}
```

In the updated code, we first replace the colon ":" in the input string with an empty string. Then we iterate through the list of formats and try to parse the input string using each format. The output should now show the expected date and time value in the "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss" format.